# SQL Query to sum buckets

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with inovices and a field named `Arrers` days and I need to count how many items are into 0-30 days also 30-90 and 90-120

Basically what I need is to calcuate the aging of my client portfolio.

so far I have this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Receivable.Arrers>'0'<'30' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS 0-30,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Receivable.Arrers<'30'>'60' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS 30-60, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Receivable.Arrers<'90'>'120' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS 90-120 
From Receivable
```

Table Name Receivable

```
Invoice   Arrers    
89859       10  
89856       3  
89853       11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL does not support `CASE WHEN`.  You can use an [`IIf`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) expression instead.

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(IIf(r.Arrers BETWEEN  0 AND  30, 1, 0)) AS [0-30],
    SUM(IIf(r.Arrers BETWEEN 31 AND  60, 1, 0)) AS [31-60], 
    SUM(IIf(r.Arrers BETWEEN 90 AND 120, 1, 0)) AS [90-120] 
FROM Receivable AS r;
```

The example in your question ignores `Arrers` from 61 to 89, so I did, too.  But you can add in another column expression if needed.

If `Arrers` is text instead of numeric datatype, you can use `Val()` to cast the text values to numbers ...

```
SUM(IIf(Val(r.Arrers) BETWEEN  0 AND  30, 1, 0)) AS [0-30]
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, this is what you want now: `SUM(IIf(r.Arrers BETWEEN  0 AND  30, r.AmountLC, 0))`

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm :) yeah a i replaced also the 1 to r.AmountLC to get the ammount in the  report

Comment: Oh, I missed the `ms-access` tag. +1 here

Answer (score 1):

You can try that one

```
SELECT 
       SUM( CASE WHEN Receivable.Arrers BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS '0-30',
       SUM (CASE WHEN Receivable.Arrers BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS '30-60',
       SUM (CASE WHEN Receivable.Arrers BETWEEN 90 AND 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS '90-120',
       arrers
FROM Receivable
GROUP BY arrers
```

1 thing need to be checked.

1. I've put `BETWEEN 90 AND 120` as I consider it integer. If they are varchar, you will need to turn them into integers. `Val(Receivable.Arrers)` will do the trick on access. Please let me know if there is anything unclear

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track except possibly for the CASE stmt syntax .... try Andy's answer without the Group by

(Dont have enough points to post as a comment)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this:

```
SELECT subq.ArrersGroup, COUNT(*) 'Count'
FROM
(
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN R.Arrers < 30 THEN '0-30'
    WHEN R.Arrers < 90 THEN '30-90'
    WHEN R.Arrers < 120 THEN '90-120'
    ELSE 'Other'
  END ArrersGroup
FROM Receivable R
) subq
GROUP BY subq.ArrersGroup
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adb1e7/11)